# django stream json data that is created by request

Tags: python, json, django, sockets, request

how can we stream data in django i saw many tutorials but still can figure it out, 
i requested a data inside view.py and send it through the context to template.html, but i want to update the data once it got changed so i need to keep sending request but how can i create that type of connection? 
basically some thing like this:

```
webserver ---------> Wsgi -----------> urls.py 
      |                              |
      |                              |
      |     keep sending data        |        keep requesting data
templat.html<--------------------- views.py -------------------------> request
```

i dont now if we need to use sockets or how to approach this problem.

Comment: There are several ways of updating an HTML page. All involve Java Script. To explain them all or even one in details would be to complex for this format.

Answer (score 0):

The most common use case of what you want to do is endless pagination, when you have lots of data and you do not want to retrieve them in one request. Instead, you request data multiple times and update your front end. 
Try to use django-el-pagination django package, it can help you with your problem. [django-el-pagination](https://github.com/shtalinberg/django-el-pagination) on GitHub.